# Welcome back Jon Ericson!

Tags: discussion, moderators

I was surprised that there wasn't any kind of post noting this yet, so here, let me make one:

Welcome back Jon! It will be great to have you as a mod here!

(Though I don't think I was actually a member here when you became staff ;))

Comment: Agreed - welcome back Jon! I have mainly read your posts from previous years, and look forward to having more of your influence on the site. Compared to other years, there's definitely a gap right now with regards to welcoming and engaging new users positively. Every little intervention here and there pays dividends in shaping the site well :)

Answer (score 7):

I hope I will serve you all better than I have in the last 10 days. I just now noticed a new meta post!

On a more serious note, I have not found a better way to learn and understand the texts of the Bible than this site. After everything that [happened in 2019](https://jlericson.com/2020/02/02/2019_in_review.html), I seriously considered leaving the Stack Exchange network altogether. But there were two things that stopped me from leaving:

1. I believe the company behind Stack Overflow can turn itself around if it starts listening to the remaining community management team. Before I left the company, other CMs asked if I'd be interested in sticking around as a moderator and participate in providing feedback to the company. I said I'd consider it.
2. This community remains dear to me even though I have not been as engaged as I once was. I'd like to start answering (and maybe asking) questions again. It was a very rewarding hobby before I became a community manager and I imagine it can be again now that visiting the sites isn't part of my job.

So I'm glad to be back and I hope I will do my duty as moderator in a way that support you all.